# What is kernel dynamic memory in linux systems and how to free it

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, shared-memory

This question is related to
https://serverfault.com/questions/896282/cannot-explain-memory-occupancy-in-linux/896525#896525
and to 
[How to correctly identify and correct a memory leak on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467569/how-to-correctly-identify-and-correct-a-memory-leak-on-a-server)

What is kernel dynamic memory? I have virtually no process running in my workstation now

```
$ ps aux --sort -rss | head
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        987  0.0  0.0  54284 15932 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:03 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
imoline+  49734  0.0  0.0  24640  8672 pts/0    Ss+  Feb13   0:05 /bin/bash
rstudio+   4803  0.0  0.0 128608  7400 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:39 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver
imoline+  53699  0.0  0.0  23356  7224 pts/2    Ss   Feb13   0:04 /bin/bash
imoline+  68563  0.0  0.0  23200  6876 pts/1    Ss   10:37   0:00 -bash
root          1  0.0  0.0 204660  6804 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:05 /sbin/init
root      68556  0.0  0.0  99308  6800 ?        Ss   10:37   0:00 sshd: imolineris [priv]
root       4770  0.0  0.0  69944  6484 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

but still I have memory occupied according to `free`

```
$ free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            125          67          56           0           1          57
Swap:           119           0         119
```

and to `smem`

```
$ sudo smem -t -w -p 
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware             0.00%      0.00%      0.00% 
kernel image                  0.00%      0.00%      0.00% 
kernel dynamic memory        54.68%      1.25%     53.43% 
userspace memory              0.06%      0.03%      0.03% 
free memory                  45.26%     45.26%      0.00% 
----------------------------------------------------------
                            100.00%     46.54%     53.46%
```

Can I force to free it somehow without rebooting?

Comment: try running following commands to see if it frees up memory (https://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches) :
 1] "sync;echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
 2] "sync;echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
 3] "sync;echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"

Comment: @PrabhakarLad `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` did the trick. But I should expect that this cache is automatically freed if some process need RAM? It seemed to me that this do not happen and the system start swapping.

Comment: you have loads of RAM, and you aren’t running out  of memory, when your applications starts eating up RAM, and you reach the threshold that is when the kernel frees up the memory.

Answer (score 1):

As you have no responses, I will make one in the general sense without dealing with Linux specifics.

Most operating system need to allocate dynamic memory for their own purposes. This memory is located with the system space region of the virtual address space. Thus, kernel dynamic memory is accessible to all processes when they are executing in kernel mode. On some systems, this dynamic memory is further broken down into "paged" and "non-paged".

Notice the distinction:

```
kernel dynamic memory        54.68%      1.25%     53.43% 
userspace memory              0.06%      0.03%      0.03%
```

Think of all the data structures the operating system has to maintain (e.g. process state definitions, page tables) as well as buffers for doing I/O.

Yes, there can be kernel memory leaks. The fact that you have memory allocated to the kernel does not necessarily mean there is a leak.